# tengo un problema al querer actualizar las dependencias me da este error en la termina

Tags: flutter, dart

este es el error

```bash
[tuntun-flutter] flutter pub get --no-example
No se esperaba << en este momento.
exit code 255
```

y cuando quiero hacer debug no me salen los dispositivos que tengo conectado ni el navegador donde puedo hacer el debug

trabajo con flutter y dart.

Probé en reiniciar el IDE y actualizar el pubspec.ymal